# Compare aggregate of column with another column of same table

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table `D_MARK` with following layout,

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+
| CLAS_ID | MARK      | MARK_THRESHOLD          |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 9001    |         5 |                    10   |
| 9001    |        10 |                    10   |
| 9004    |         5 |                    10   |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I'm trying to create a **View** from this table based on following logic:-

1.Need to do sum(`MARK`) group by `CLAS_ID`.

2.Need to showcase sum(`MARK`) as FINAL_MARK such that, `if sum(MARK) > MARK_THRESHOLD then MARK_THRESHOLD else sum(MARK)`

Expected Output:-

```
+---------+-----------+
| CLAS_ID | FINAL_MARK|
+---------+-----------+
| 9001    |        10 |
| 9004    |         5 |
+---------+-----------+
```

So this is what I've done so far,

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS SELECT CLAS_ID, SUM(CASE WHEN SUM(MARK) > MARK_THRESHOLD THEN MARK_THRESHOLD ELSE SUM(MARK) END) AS FINAL_MARK 
FROM `D_MARK` GROUP BY CLAS_ID;
```

On executing this I'm getting, `Invalid use of group function` error. I'm guessing using an aggregate function within case is a big no?

So I was wondering if someone could help me out a bit as I'm pretty new to this. Thanks in advance.

P.S. `MARK_THRESHOLD` will be the same for a particular `CLAS_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate also with `MAX()` (or `MIN()` it does not matter) on `MARK_THRESHOLD`:

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS 
SELECT CLAS_ID, 
       LEAST(SUM(MARK), MAX(MARK_THRESHOLD)) AS FINAL_MARK 
FROM D_MARK 
GROUP BY CLAS_ID
```

Use the function [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) instead of the `CASE` expression.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iTMSTjU8ixYRUuxin7ABef/0).
Results:

```
| CLAS_ID | FINAL_MARK |
| ------- | ---------- |
| 9001    | 10         |
| 9004    | 5          |
```

Comment: Much appreciated.